# Why Inception V3 retrained using tensorflow and keras on same dataset shows different accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to retrain Inception V3 pretrained on ImageNet dataset.

******* Keras (Using Tensorflow backend ) ************

I have retrained **Inception V3 using Keras**(tensorflow backend) with following code :

```
# SETUP MODEL
CLASSES = 3
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
preds=Dense(CLASSES,activation='softmax')(x) #final layer with softmax activation

model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=preds)

# transfer learning
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer='adam',metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the network
print("[INFO] training network...")
H = model.fit_generator(
    aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1, callbacks=[csv_logger])
```

After training for 100 epochs , I get an accuracy between **85% to 90%** as shown in plot : [Training result  using Keras plor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5suy.png)

********    Tensorflow  **********

I have also retrained Inception V3 pretrained on ImageNet using Tensorflow following the link : [How to Retrain an Image Classifier for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining) .
After 4000 Iterations , I am getting an accuracy between **93% to 96%** as shown in plot below : [Training result using Tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrltd.png)

**Could anyone please help me to find the explanation for this reason or please point out the the mistake (if any) , for my interpretation.**

Actually in Keras I am using :

lower learning rate = 0.001 
epochs = 100 and Batch size = 32
Data Augmentation with

```
aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=25, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")
```

**On the other hand :**

In tensorflow , I am using

higher learning rate = 0.01

**No** Augmentation techniques .

But it appears that , the tensorflow model achieves higher accuracy. 
If anyone is aware of any tricks tensorflow [How to Retrain an Image Classifier for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining) uses or any possible logical reason to this difference , please help me to understand.

Comment: Looks like you're running Tensorflow longer.  Wouldn't you expect that to give you higher accuracy?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your reply ...... I have ran in keras for 1000 epochs too , but it is just overfitting more , accuracy does not improve. By the way , is there any way to compare iterations and epochs in general ?

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of reasons you might see differences.  I think the more important part is looking into some things you might want to learn during your journey here.

First you should be checking accuracy every x epochs.  If the accuracy doesn't improve after say, 3 epochs you need to end your training.

You need to have a somewhat even number of images in each class or one class will be over-represented in your batch.

You probably want to include some augmentation techniques to your pipeline in order to prevent overfitting.  This includes rotating, cropping, blurring, noising, etc on a percentage of your images as they are fed into the batch.  This can also help solve the problem of not having enough images per class.

You're probably not choosing the best learning rate either, which is important.

I would suggest looking at fast.ai section on image classification and switching to the fastai library over tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: I understood that there are many factors I need to consider. But in Keras I am using lower learning rate with data augmentation techniques . On the other hand , in tensorflow , I am not using any data augmentation techniques . But still tensorflow model achieves higher accuracy.  In both cases I am using same model (Inception V3) pretrained on ImageNet and added only one FCL and softmax layer for new classes.